# GPU cannot be indentified to run module

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I have 2 GPU machine available to use with ID 2 and 3, and would like to use them all to fit model. Here is my code,

```
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '2, 3'
```

with tf,device('/gpu:2'):

```
critic_model.fit(x,y,epochs =10)
```

with tf.device('/gpu:3'):

```
history = model.fit(x,y,epochs=19)
```

However, when I check nvidia-smi, I found only machine 2 is utilized, I wonder why ?

Any idea could be helpful !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple problems here:

For one, Tensorflow has "its own" GPU numbering independent from the IDs on your machine. So when you pass `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2,3`, Tensorflow will see those two GPUs, but they will be `'/gpu:0'` and `'/gpu:1'` in the program. Since neither `'/gpu:2'` nor `'/gpu:3'` exist, I suspect that all ops are simply put on `'/gpu:0'` or the CPU.

However, the main problem is that this is not how you use `with tf.device` at all. You need to wrap *the model creation* into the context manager. I.e. all the op calls such as `tf.nn.conv2d`, `tf.matmul` etc. need to be wrapped. At the point you call `model.fit`, the ops have already been created (and put on `'/gpu:0'` by default) and your `with tf.device` statement does nothing.

Comment: OK I got it, what if I change "/gpu:0" and "/gpu:1" to indicate GPU of ID 2 and 3, would it push tensorflow to run module on GPU 2 and 3 ?

Comment: It should, however as I said it will have no effect if you do it around the `model.fit` call; you need to use `tf.device` where you actually _define_ the models. And this will _not_ parallelize the two `fit` calls either. The first one will be done on GPU2 and then when it's done the second one will start on GPU3.

Comment: OK, I will try. Thx mate.